# How to filter for value in one column based on values from other columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, filter, multiple-columns

Here is my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(label = c(1,2,3,4,5), measurement = c(100.5, 84.7, 100.7, 77.9, 98.8), size = c(20, 19, 20, 20, 15))
```

Now I want to be able to obtain the label (from label column) that has the maximum size. However, as in the example above, three of the labels have the maximum value of 20. I want my tie breaker to be the measurement values. So in this case, out of the three values of 20 from the size column, measurement of 100.7 is the greatest.

So I would run the code and it would return 3 has the label I should go with. How can I do this across columns?

Comment: Have you thought about dupes in the value columns? See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65630459/6574038) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order` the dataframe in descending order based on `size` and `measurement` column and then extract the first `label` from it.

```
df1 <- df[with(df, order(-size, -measurement)), ]
df1$label[1]
#[1] 3
```

Or sort them in ascending order and extract the last value. Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(size, measurement) %>%
  pull(label) %>% last
#[1] 3
```

Comment: That doesn't take duplicates into account, though, resp. it omits them.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter()` function from `dplyr` will operate sequentially when specified as comma separated arguments. You can do something like this to filter to the observation and then `pull()` the label.

This method will give you multiple responses if the tiebreaker is also tied.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(size == max(size), measurement == max(measurement)) %>% 
  pull(label)
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line in base R:

```
df[order(df$size, df$measurement, decreasing = TRUE)[1], "label"]
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Nice, but think `df <- rbind(df, c(label=6, measurement=100.7, size=20))`. Accepted answer also doesn't consider this. `dplyr` even yields `6`.

Comment: @jay.sf sorry I don't see the issue here. The two observations will be tied?

Comment: Exactly not, i.e. ties won't be returned, just one observation will be displayed, the others omitted. Try with the data from my answer.

Comment: Good to be aware of it but I think we cannot tell which solution the OP would prefer. He doesn't mention that corner case.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably wise to work with `rank` here, to account for duplicates (in contrast to `order`, which selects the first maximum and `dplyr::last` the last, thus omitting the other maxima).

Think of this data frame with duplicates in the value columns:

```
df
#   label measurement size
# 1     1       100.5   20
# 2     2        84.7   19
# 3     3       100.7   20  ## !
# 4     4        77.9   20
# 5     5        98.8   15
# 6     6       100.7   20  ## !
```

We would add the `rowSums` of the `rank`s of the value columns and add the `rank` of the "tie breaker" *size* and finally subset the *levels* on the `max`ima.

```
rankv <- Vectorize(rank)
R <- rankv(df[-1])  ## or `apply(df[-1], 2, rank)`
r <- rowSums(R) + rank(R[,2])
df$label[r == max(r)]
# [1] 3 6
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(label = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), measurement = c(100.5, 
84.7, 100.7, 77.9, 98.8, 100.7), size = c(20, 19, 20, 20, 15, 
20)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```